# Construct pandas DataFrame from nested dictionaries having list as item

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have several dictionary data and I want to convert to Pandas DataFrame.
However, due to unnecessary key '0' (for me), I've obtained undesirable format of DataFrame when I convert these dict to DataFrame. Actually, these dicts are short part of whole data.

```
dict1 = {1: {0: [-0.022, -0.017]},
         2: {0: [0.269, 0.271]},
         3: {0: [0.118, 0.119]},
         4: {0: [0.057, 0.061]},
         5: {0: [-0.916, -0.924]}}

dict2 = {1: {0: [0.384, 0.398]},
         2: {0: [0.485, 0.489]},
         3: {0: [0.465, 0.469]},
         4: {0: [0.456, 0.468]},
         5: {0: [-0.479, -0.482]}}

dict3 = {1: {0: [-0.323, -0.321]},
         2: {0: [-0.535, -0.534]},
         3: {0: [-0.336, -0.336]},
         4: {0: [-0.140, -0.142]},
         5: {0: [0.175, 0.177]}}

DataFrame(dict1)

                  1               2               3               4  \
0  [-0.022, -0.017]  [0.269, 0.271]  [0.118, 0.119]  [0.057, 0.061]   

                  5  
0  [-0.916, -0.924]
```

I've solved this problem using 'for' iteration and the result is what I want to obtain finally.

```
    index = [['dict1', 'dict1', 'dict2', 'dict2', 'dict3', 'dict3'], ['A', 'B']*3]
    dict = DataFrame(index = index)
    for k in dict1.keys():
        dict = dict.join(DataFrame(dict1[k][0]+dict2[k][0]+dict3[k][0], index = index, columns = [k]))

    print dict

             1      2      3      4      5
dict1 A -0.022  0.269  0.118  0.057 -0.916
      B -0.017  0.271  0.119  0.061 -0.924
dict2 A  0.384  0.485  0.465  0.456 -0.479
      B  0.398  0.489  0.469  0.468 -0.482
dict3 A -0.323 -0.535 -0.336 -0.140  0.175
      B -0.321 -0.534 -0.336 -0.142  0.177
```

However, when I apply this method to whole length of data, I couldn't wait until the operation was done. 
I've also found method using 'Panel'. It reduced the time but not satisfied yet.

```
pd.Panel.from_dict(dict1).to_frame()
```

Please let me know the best way for this simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply drop a level from your nested dict to make life easier.  The code below drops the unnecessary part of your dicts and concatenates the dataframes from each of the dicts together.

```
all_dicts=[dict1,dict2,dict3]
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({k:v[0] for k,v in d.items()}) for d in all_dicts])
df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['dict1','dict2','dict3'],['A','B']])

>>> df 
             1      2      3      4      5
dict1 A -0.022  0.269  0.118  0.057 -0.916
      B -0.017  0.271  0.119  0.061 -0.924
dict2 A  0.384  0.485  0.465  0.456 -0.479
      B  0.398  0.489  0.469  0.468 -0.482
dict3 A -0.323 -0.535 -0.336 -0.140  0.175
      B -0.321 -0.534 -0.336 -0.142  0.177
```

Comment: Thanks, khammel. This code reduce the time greatly. Then, I've found your code reduce the time than native reading method df = pd.DataFrame(dict1). Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment @Sunkist.  I did use pd.DataFrame() on each of your dict's, however, what I did was apply a dict comprehension using each of them to strip out the nested zeros.  pd.concat() just took all three of the DataFrame's from dict's and concatenates them all together.

Comment: I'm sorry for making you confused, khammel. My question is basic one. In your comment @khammel, I thought '{k:v[0] for k,v in d.items()}' needs additional works(time) to construct dictionary again. However, pd.DataFrame({k:v[0] for k,v in d.items()}) shows shorter time than pd.DataFrame(d) even though both {k:v[0] for k,v in d.items()} and d are dictionaries. This is only my curiosity.

Comment: You'd have to work your way through all the methods called when you initialize a DataFrame in the pandas code.  I suspect that by removing nested data it is only seen as a grouping of columns to convert to DataFrame (just key value pairs to parse where the value is a series like list).  Whereas in the original case it needs to loop through the dict of dict's at different levels determining what data is in the columns, index and data.

Comment: I've understood nested dictionary making additional loop. I couldn't think about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify your input data and convert it to `DataFrame`:

```
import itertools

lst = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
dict = {}

for k in dict1:
    temp = [l[k].itervalues().next() for l in lst]
    dict[k] = list(itertools.chain(*temp))

dict['row']  = ['A','B']*len(lst)
dict['dict'] = ['dict'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(lst)) for n in range(2)]

In [23]: pd.DataFrame(dict)
Out[23]:
       1      2      3      4      5   dict row
0 -0.022  0.269  0.118  0.057 -0.916  dict1   A
1 -0.017  0.271  0.119  0.061 -0.924  dict1   B
2  0.384  0.485  0.465  0.456 -0.479  dict2   A
3  0.398  0.489  0.469  0.468 -0.482  dict2   B
4 -0.323 -0.535 -0.336 -0.140  0.175  dict3   A
5 -0.321 -0.534 -0.336 -0.142  0.177  dict3   B
```

Comment: Thanks, Colonel. In my case, your advice needed more time than using pd.Panel.from_dict(dict1).to_frame()